# InputStream fails to open file

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

Writing some tests for an Android app and a failure occurs when trying to open a file. My hunch is something is breaking down when passing the context.

Here's how I pass in the context

testFactoryQueued.java:

```
 Object obj = Factory.getInstance(getInstrumentation().getContext());
```

which goes to

Factory.java

```
private static Factory mInstance;
private Context mContext;          

public static Factory getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new Factory(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private Factory(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

// Try to open file
try {
    InputStream is = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open(inFile);

    ...etc...

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.PrintStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest.